# How do I use JAXB/XJC to convert an XML file to an object?

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I have been doing research on JAXB and XJC but from the documentation that is [out there](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/xjc.html), including the Oracle pages and some of the Stack Overflow questions here, I don't think there is a clear definition of what is the difference between JAXB and XJC and how to use it to convert an XML file to an object.

So from my understanding JAXB is method for XML -> Java parsing and vice versa and xjc is one implementation for it that is included in the java tools?

Comment: I wasn't asking for code guys... I just wanted a clearer explanation of what XJC was, the stackoverflow makes it impossible to ask questions, please explain instead of just marking it as off-topic

Comment: I revisited this question I asked 5 months ago, would the edits that I have made, make it on-topic? This question has received quite a few views (1000+) and is upvoted.

Comment: Its 2019 and I still have the question. It will be helpful for someone who is starting new. And yes, xjc is a command line tool for converting xml to java, while Jaxb is a object that can help write XML/read as POJO (marshal/unmarshal) that data in your java code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementations convert instances of Java classes (that may contain annotations) to/from XML.  XJC (XML to Java Compiler) is a utility for generating those objects from an XML schema.  It is included as part of the JDK since Java SE 6.

**Exanple**

Here is a link to my blog that demonstrates how to generate a Java model from an XML Schema:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/09/processing-atom-feeds-with-jaxb.html

Comment: That makes more sense now... thanks for the blog post as well, it was helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is what you're after but it seems close...

Use Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) xjc tooling to compile an XML schema file into fully annotated Java classes.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/twbs_jaxbschema2java.html